# Get author names from CrossRef (get text out of JSON)

Tags: json, string, bash, jq, doi

I'm trying to get the author names of [this paper](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fpls.2011.00050/full) by using the CrossRef API with curl.

```
curl -LH "Accept: application/citeproc+json" http://dx.doi.org/10.3389/fpls.2011.00050 | jq .author
```

Of course I get a JSON as response, but rather need pure text for further bash processing:

```
[
  {
    "given": "Fabio",
    "family": "Facchinelli",
    "affiliation": []
  },
  {
    "given": "Andreas P. M.",
    "family": "Weber",
    "affiliation": []
  }
]
```

I thought of using jq, but couldn't figure out, how to just get:

"Fabio Facchinelli, Andreas P. M. Weber"

Do you know a solution (must not be jq)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that with `jq`:

```
... | jq '.author[] | .given + " " + .family' | jq -s 'join(", ")'
```

Outputs:

> ```
> "Fabio Facchinelli, Andreas P. M. Weber"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Can do it with a sed script:

```
$ cat json.sed
/"given":/{
    s/^.*"given"://
    s/[",]//g
    h
}
/"family":/{
    s/^.*"family"://
    s/[",]//g
    G
    s/\n/, /
    p
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
$ sed -n -f json.sed curl.json 
 Facchinelli,  Fabio
 Weber,  Andreas P. M.
```

Answer (score 0):

The task can be accomplished with just one invocation of jq:

```
 ... | jq '.author | map(.given + " " + .family) | join(", ")'
```